# Apply conditional formatting on whole column/sheet with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to add conditional formatting on an excel file in Python for the whole file so that it is applied too even if the user adds new lines

[excel equivalent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLjzH.png)

The red rule is the one from the code below. The blue rule is the one expected and finally, the white rule is the one generated by Excel when selecting the whole Sheet.

Here is the following code from [the official documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html#formatting-entire-rows). Replacing `E1:E10` with `E:E` or `E` returns an error.

Is there a way to make sure the conditional formating rule is applied even on new lines?

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
# Create fill
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')

# Format using a formula
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E1:E10', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISBLANK(E1))'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=redFill))

wb.save("test2.xlsx")
```

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do what you want even in Excel itself.

Comment: I agree with @BoarGules. Why you don't use a big number ('E1:E1000000', for example)?

Comment: Your code works for me, I opened it using LibreOffice, added two lines. If I fill the new cells they are colored and the conditional format shows the new range E1:E12

Comment: @MuriloSitonio is there any performance problem you can expect by using big numbers? Else it might be a proper solution, as even Excel uses it when applying to the whole sheet: **$1:$1048576**

Comment: Internally Excel maps `E:E` to `E1:E1048576` so this is what you should do as well.