# how to remove ConditionalFormattingList in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

who to create a conditional_formatting for a whole column,or  remove the old conditional_formatting?

1.I want to add a conditional_formatting for a whole column,But failed.

2.then I change the 'E:E'->'E2:E10',it workd.
but the E:10 is dynamic， may increase with data. May change to E:100.
i found no way .

on  python 3.7  win10 pro  openpyxl 2.6.3

```py
#1.I want to add a conditional_formatting for a whole column,But failed.
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E:E',
                              CellIsRule(operator='==',
                                         formula=['"Fail"'],
                                         stopIfTrue=False,
                                         fill=redFill)
                              )
```

```py
#2.then I change the 'E:E'->'E2:E10',it workd.
#but the E:10 is dynamic， may increase with data. May change to E:100.
# i found no way .
for i in ws.conditional_formatting:
    print(i.cells.ranges[0].bounds)
    ##(5, 1, 5, 10)
    #print(i.key)
    # 如果是单独给E列的都删除重新建立
    #if the conditional_formatting only for E column ,if want to remve the old one.
    from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
    if column_index_from_string("E")==i.cells.ranges[0].bounds[0] and column_index_from_string("E")==i.cells.ranges[0].bounds[2]:
        del ws.conditional_formatting[i.key]#failed
```

```py
File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\formatting.py", line 75, in add
    cf = ConditionalFormatting(range_string)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\formatting.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.sqref = sqref
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange'>
```

```py
(5, 1, 5, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/MyPython/Studty/1.3处理excel-openpyxl/10单元格设置条件格式.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(i.key)
AttributeError: 'ConditionalFormatting' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apply-conditional-formatting-on-whole-column-sheet-with-openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224611/apply-conditional-formatting-on-whole-column-sheet-with-openpyxl), note the last comment.

Comment: Internally Excel maps `E:E` to `E1:E1048576` so you can just use that.